# edit item' is not allowed for this view within datagrid wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using WPF `DataGrid` and I'm unable to edit data in it. When I double click a cell I get the error listed in the discussion name:

> 'Edit item' is not allowed for this view.

How can I overcome this ?

Thanks

**Edit:**
There are two data in my students' name and what they want to say, both of string. Then, I'm binding with my entityframework.

**Below is my selectionchanged function**

```
private void ClassDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedStudent = (Class)e.AddedItems[0];

        var sayingCollection = selectedStudent.;

        sayingCollection.AssociationChanged += ColumnsCollection_Changed;
        var sayingViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("StudentsSayingViewSource")));

        sayingViewSource.Source = sayingCollection.Where(c => c.Saying.Contains(":"));
    }
```

Comment: What data do you have there? What is data source of the `DataGrid`?

Comment: their is option of EditOnly (or any thing like this) in xaml. Check that.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez I have checked my XML; there's nothing that is set only (like IsReadOnly).

Comment: <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single">
Here you can see "IsReadOnly" is set to true. This will not allow me to edit the table.

Comment: Can you upload your xaml here as well. May be we can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?xj25l6f39fncjb6
Here is my XML. Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Let You confirm us whether you bound a Collection Item such as either IList , ObservableCollection or IEnumerable in the ItemSource.

Because the IEnumerable object doesn't have an add\remove property. So You couldn't modify the collection.